# Failed on consuming Kafka topic with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I got the Timeout Error while trying to read data from Kafka topic with pyspark.
My spark version is 2.4.5.

My python code:

```py
df = (
    # connect to kafka brokers
    (
        spark.read.format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_brokers)
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
        .option("includeHeaders", "true")
        .load()
    )
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "message",
    f.from_json(
        f.col("value").cast("string"),
        kafka_schema,
        {"timestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"},
    )
).drop("value")

df.show()
```

Then I got the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition DVI_COMBINED_SUID_LOG-22 could be determined
```

I don't know where to start debugging. I check my Kafka server and everything is fined. Other consumers work smoothly except my Spark session.

Comment: I have only used Kafka with Spark streaming (readstream instead of read) so are you sure you can read Kafka data this way (I mean reading it in single batch without timing out )? Check details [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi Yes, `read` works fine, and is documented on that page.

Comment: How did you "check the Kafka server"? What is the value of `kafka_topic`? Please show a [mcve]... Can you show the output of `kafka-topics.sh --describe <kafka_topic>`

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketeer I phrased it incorrectly I meant can he try reading it in micro batches instead of the single batch to check if it times out or not

Comment: Do the workers on the cluster have access to kafka cluster? Are you providing the ports along with broker endpoints?

Comment: Hi all, thank you all for supporting me. Due to this error, I spent time on working with networking team and find out some problems with our networking system. The root cause is connection between my spark cluster and the Kafka brokers is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

For this error, I have to check following element in my system:

- Kafka cluster: `./kafka-topic.sh --describe`
- Networking: check firewall, routes, ...

My problem is caused be unstable connection between Spark workers and Kafka brokers. Sometimes Spark workers can not establish new connection. I tried with telnet command on Linux to check if all my workers can connect to Kafka broker list. Some workers can not connect to Kafka brokers, then I check with network team to update firewall rules. After re-configure firewall rules, all Spark workers can connect to Kafka brokers stably and the problem is solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).